# Python string formatting issue

Tags: python, string

```
import random

def main():
    the_number = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = 0
    no_of_tries = 0
    while guess != the_number:
        no_of_tries += 1
        guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
        if guess < the_number:
            print "--------------------------------------"
            print "Guess higher!", "You guessed:", guess
            if guess == the_number - 1:
                print "You're so close!"
        if guess > the_number:
            print "--------------------------------------"
            print "Guess lower!", "You guessed:", guess
            if guess == the_number + 1:
                print "You're so close!"
        if guess == the_number:
            print "--------------------------------------"
            print "You guessed correctly! The number was:", the_number
            print "And it only took you", no_of_tries, "tries!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Right now, in my random number guessing game, if a person guesses lower or higher by one number, they receive the following message:

```
Guess lower! You guessed: 33
You're so close!
```

But I want to make it one sentence.

For example:

```
Guess lower! You guessed: 33. You're so close!
```

How would I implement this in my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put a comma (`','`) after your `print` statement if you want to avoid it advancing to the next line. For example:

```
print "Guess lower!", "You guessed:", guess,
                                           ^
                                           |
```

The next `print` statement will add its output at *the end of this line* i.e., it will not move down to the start of the next line as you currently have.

***Update** re comment below*:

To avoid the space due to the comma, you can use the [print function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html). I.e.,

```
from __future__ import print_function  # this needs to go on the first line

guess = 33

print("Guess lower!", "You guessed:", guess, ".", sep="", end="")
print(" You're so close!")
```

This will print

> `Guess lower!You guessed:33. You're so close!`

This [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) also talks about the print function

Comment: Thanks, but if want to put a period before the message, like ". You're so close!", wouldn't there be a gap between 33 and .? Is there a way to concatenate them?

Comment: +1. The other advantage of using the print function is that your code is valid Python 3 as well as Python 2. (PS, you might want to remove the space between the print and the parens for consistency with the OP's code, and because Guido says so…)